# Simulator is slow when not connected with internet

Tags: codenameone

CN1 simulator is very slow when not connected with internet. Navigating between the forms is lagging. Any one notice same issue? Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Codename One's navigation code makes no network connection. I suggest opening the network monitor and inspecting the activity

Comment: Network monitor shows it keep hitting www.google.com continuously and after a while it gets slow down automatically and simulator lags in navigation.

Comment: I do realize even when connected to internet simulator is slow. Is it how it is or this isOffline() method making the simulator slow. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is triggered by the connectivity library, if you constantly check it this can slow down your app. Try to test it on a separate thread periodically instead of invoking it within the EDT.